# Grouping in LINQ to Entity Model

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have following fields in entity model object

MONTH_CHAR char(1)
AVG_BALANCE int
PROD_CAT_ID int
FLG_PERS_COMM chat(1)
ACCOUNT_COUNT int

I want group by MONTH_CHAR column, I 'll write following SQL Query for this

`SELECT MONTH_CHAR,
    SUM(AVG_BALANCE) AS AVG_BALANCE,
    MAX(PROD_CAT_ID) AS PROD_CAT_ID,
    MAX(ACCOUNT_COUNT) AS ACCOUNT_COUNT, 
FROM    contactSummary
WHERE   PROD_CAT_ID = 1
GROUP BY MONTH_CHAR`

I want this query to be converted to LINQ Query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want you to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from contact in context.Contacts
group contact by contact.Month_Char into g
select new 
{
    MonthChar = g.Key,
    AvgBalance = g.Average(x=>x.Avg_Balance)
    CatID = g.Max(x=>x.Prod_Cat_ID)
    AccountCount = g.Max(x=>x.Account_Count)
}
```

Comment: Your code worked well but it returned me result with an Anonymous type  but want it to convert to my specific type of parent table ``

Comment: I want the returned results to convert to my specific type of parent table i.e. type of contactSummary
I use following LINQ query

`(from res in contactSummary
            where (res.PROD_CAT_ID == 1)
            group res by res.MONTH_CHAR into g
            select new
            {
                MONTH_CHAR = g.Key,
                AVG_BALANCE = g.Sum(x => x.AVG_BALANCE),
                PROD_CAT_ID = g.Max(x => x.PROD_CAT_ID),
                FLG_PERS_COMM = "",
                ACCOUNT_COUNT = g.Max(x => x.ACCOUNT_COUNT)
            }).ToList();`